# Show that if $x(t)$ satisfies $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2-x^6$ and $x(0) >0$ then $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = 1.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Show that if $x(t)$ satisfies $\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2-x^6$ and $x(0)  = c >0$ then $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = 1.$

(Taken from "Berkeley problems in mathematics")

Here's my attempt:

The function $f(t,x) = x^2-x^6$ is continuous everywhere and locally Lipschitz. By Picard's theorem there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that there is a unique solution $x(t)$ on $[- \epsilon, \epsilon].$

By differentiability of $x(t)$ with $x'(0) \neq 0$ ( assuming $x$ is non-constant) and as $x(0)>0$ the inverse function theorem applies and there is a local continuous inverse $x^{-1}(y)$ satisfying

$$
\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^2-x^6} \implies x^{-1}(y) = \int^{y}_{c}\frac{d \xi}{\xi^2-\xi^6}.
$$

As $\frac{1}{\xi ^2- \xi^6}$ "blows up at $\xi=1$ rapidly enough" we have $x^{-1}(1) = \infty$ and by continuity of $x$, $ \lim_{t \to \infty}x(t) = 1$. $\blacksquare$

Is this correct? Many thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

In response to enzotib:

Assume $0 < c <1$.

The integral $x^{-1}(y)$ is continuous and non-zero on $(c,1)$ . Clearly $x^{-1}(c) = 0, $ and as shown $x^{-1}(1) = + \infty$. By IVT, $ x^{-1} : (c,1) \to [0, +\infty)$. Applying the inverse function theorem a second time we see that the unique solution on $[0,  \epsilon]$ can be extended to a unique solution on $[0, \infty)$. Taking should now be justified.

The case $c >1$ is much the same and the case $c =1$ forces $x(t) =1$ which solves the problem trivially.

Comment: In the title you wrote $x\to\infty$, you mean $t\to\infty$?

Comment: Woops! That would make the question rather hard :)

Comment: If the solution is defined in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon],$ how can we take the limit for $t\to\infty$? So probably you should first prove that it has solution in $[-\epsilon,+\infty)$

Comment: @enzotib That's a good point! I suppose I could do this by noting that the integral $x^{-1}(y)$ is continuous by FTC and ,after finding two suitable points in the range of $x$, use IVT to conclude.

Comment: @enzotib I have edited my attempt in response to your comments. Do you think my solution is sound now? Many thanks!

Comment: I think it is sound

Comment: Thanks! Your comments have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the ODE, we get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2(1-x^4) \implies \int \frac{dx}{x^2(1-x^4)}=t+C$$
$$\implies \int\left( \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2(1+x^2)}+\frac{1}{2(1-x^2)}\right)=t+C$$ $$ \implies -\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1} x+\frac{1}{4}[-\ln (1-x)+\ln(x+1)]=t+C$$
the last equation clearly gives $t=+\infty$ when $x=1$

Comment: Apparently you implicitly assumed $x>1$ (because of first $\log$), and probably you would write $x\to1$ instead of $x=1.$

Comment: Sorry I goofed up, I have corrected it now. You may see.

Answer (score 1):

The steady states solve

$$x^2-x^6=0$$

or $$x^2(1-x^4)=0$$

so there are three steady states $x=-1$, $x=0, x=1$. If $0<x(t)<1$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-x^6=x^2(1-x^4)>0$$

so if $0<x(0)<1$, $x(t)\rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. If $x(t)>1$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-x^6=x^2(1-x^4)<0$$

so if $x(0)>1$, $x(t)\rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

More formally we can note that if $x(0)>1$, continuity and the fact that $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ at $x=1$ implies that $x(t)$ is bounded below by $1$. Now $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}x(t)=1$ follows from monotone convergence theorem as $x(t+T)<x(t)$ for $T>0$. This works similarly for $0<x(0)<1$.

Comment: I cannot understand the main conclusion in both cases, why the limit is $1,$ can you provide more details?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be honest I was looking for improvements/verification of the solution I proposed rather than an entirely different solution.

Comment: For example if $x(0)>1$, the derivative is $\frac{dx}{dt}<0$ so $x(t)$ decreases until $x(t)=1$. If the limit exists it must be the steady state value $1$. I agree that you might want to add a more rigorous argument why the limit exists.

Comment: Why the limit must be the steady state value?

Comment: What are "periods"? The function $x=2+(1/t)$ is always above $1$, is always decreasing, but $x\to2.$

Comment: I mean $x(t+T)<x(t)$ for $T>0$ when $\frac{dx(s)}{ds}<0$ for all $s \in [t,t+T]$.

Comment: @enzotib I added some detail to the answer.